# tabular data (charts) not displaying in browser based email clients

Tags: html, email, debugging, html-email, email-client

An external vendor made a template for our organization to use in a proprietary crm. The issue is that our users want include large tables(as in charts containing tabular data) to send out to our clients. When testing the code in litmus it appears as though browser based clients simply remove these tables in part or in whole. We were guessing it was because their width exceeded 600px (sometimes they were as wide as 1200px). But in the included example, the width is under 600px and the table is still omitted. Any suggestions are appreciated. Furthermore, if anyone has any suggestions as to how to deal with such large tables in a mobile context that would ve great.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
<strong>&nbsp;Commitment</strong>
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
<strong>&nbsp;</strong>
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
<strong>&nbsp;Expected Date</strong>
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
<strong>&nbsp;Monthly Donation</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
&nbsp;100,000.00
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name B McNamename
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Name A McNamename&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
Wednesday, April 8, 2008&nbsp;
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; padding: 8px;" valign="top" >
100,000.00&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The width of a `<table>` might break the email's layout, but it shouldn't make it disappear. When you say "browser based clients simply remove these tables in part or in whole"... do you mean the entire table and contents are not visible? Or that table markup is gone but the data is still there?

Comment: In this case the entire table is gone. I've been fooling around with the <table> width/omitting it to no avail.

Comment: I just ran the above code through Litmus and the table displayed in every mobile client. It also appears when I sent it to my iPhone using iOS Mail and iOS Outlook. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the `<table>` structure, so I recommend looking at the email code _outside_ of this `<table>` snippet. What's in the `<head>`, CSS resets, and any weird or malformed markup _around_ this table.

Comment: Your right. Turns out there was a parent table with the styling "font-size: 0px;" which was in turn inherited by the <td> tags in certain situations. Thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Also, for anyone else that might stumble on to this post. I've found that
<td style= "word-break:break-all;" works well for when long words are breaking table width styling.